# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' flutter new

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not getting output on my app and it should have give a output like many question is how to sisplay json data in my flutter app

```
class AppState extends State<AppName>{
   var name ;
   var email ;
   int cgpa ;
   TextEditingController user = new TextEditingController();
   String url = 'http://10.42.0.243:8000/students/';

getData(String username) async{
String profile = url+'?search='+username;
var res = await http.get(profile,headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
print(res.body);
debugPrint(res.body);
var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
name = resBody['sname'].toString();
email = resBody['email'].toString();
cgpa = resBody['cgpa']  ;
debugPrint(name);
setState(() {
  print("Success");

 });
}
```

[my app screenshot is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ5Qt.jpg)

[JSON Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHioT.jpg)

Error output:
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Moto G 5 Plus...
Reloaded 0 of 576 libraries in 389ms.
E/BpSurfaceComposerClient(28411): Failed to transact (-1)
E/BpSurfaceComposerClient(28411): Failed to transact (-1)
I/flutter (28411): [{"id":1,"sname":"Ashutosh Lokhande","email":"2016bit053@sggs.ac.in","year":"2016","cgpa":7.2}]
I/flutter (28411): [{"id":1,"sname":"Ashutosh Lokhande","email":"2016bit053@sggs.ac.in","year":"2016","cgpa":7.2}]
E/flutter (28411): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (28411): #0      AppState.getData (package:json_flutter/main.dart:28:19)
E/flutter (28411): 
E/flutter (28411): #1      AppState.build. (package:json_flutter/main.dart:56:34)
E/flutter (28411): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:654:14)
E/flutter (28411): #3      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:729:32)
E/flutter (28411): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (28411): #5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
E/flutter (28411): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
E/flutter (28411): #7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)
E/flutter (28411): #8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:75:13)
E/flutter (28411): #9      PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:102:11)
E/flutter (28411): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (28411): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (28411): #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (28411): #13     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (28411): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (28411): #15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (28411): #16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (28411): #17     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (28411): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:263:10)
E/flutter (28411): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:172:5)
E/flutter (28411):

Comment: You should post your JSON output. This seems to be an JSON parsing error.

Comment: try this cgpa = int.parse(resBody['cgpa']); because your cgpa variable is int.

Comment: added screenshot of JSON data

Comment: cgpa = int.parse(resBody['cgpa']);  tried this still the same error,plz help